Is there a planar graph mapping onto sphere that has equilibrium like Tutte embedding in the plane?
I worked on the question and thought I may ask here.
So question is, whether there is an embedding of a 3-connected or maximal planar graph onto sphere (with great circle arcs as edges) so that each vertex coordinate satisfies similar equilibrium equation as non-outerface vertices in Tutte planar embedding? Best would be such an equilibrium that has no forced vertex positions like the outer face vertices in Tutte embedding.
I learned that stereographic projection of planar embedding on z=-1 plane through sphere south pole maps straight line edges in plane onto spherical circle arcs on sphere (only very few are great circle arcs):

As the image shows left, a great circle arc would produce an intersection, the spherical circle arc through the intermediate grey points does not intersect.
I have working implementation for "stereographic projection" online:
https://hermann-sw.github.io/planar_graph_playground/
You select a graph, modify eg. by selecting "dual" and press "stereographic projection". The jscad.app animation "scale" slider shows the effect of different scaling values of a Tutte embedding on the sphere. This embedding with sperical circle arcs has no edge crossings:

Details of the implemntation and on planar_graph_playground repo used here:
https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=2253258#p2253258
